# Inequality for log-likelihood ratio

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, inequalities, it.information-theory

Let $ p, q $ be two probability densities on $ [0,1] $, strictly positive over $ (0,1) $. Let $ P $ be the cumulative function of $ p $, i.e., $ P(x) = \int_0^x p(x') \, \mathrm{d}x' $, $ x \in [0,1] $. Suppose that, for some constant $ b \in (0,1] $, the following condition holds: $ \frac{q(P(x))}{p(x)} \geqslant b^2 $ for all $ x \in [0,1] $.

I would like to prove the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \log\frac{q(x)}{p(x)} \mathrm{d}x \geqslant \log\frac{1+ab}{1+a\frac{1}{b}}
\end{equation}
where $ a = \max\left\{ b(p_\max - 1), \frac{1}{b}(q_\max - 1) \right\} ,$ $ p_\max = \sup p(x) $, $ q_\max = \sup q(x) $. Note that the right-hand side is $ \leqslant\!0 $.

P.S. There are (physical) reasons to believe that the inequality holds, but the explanation would take a lot of space. I have tried to simplify it and state it in a clear manner (and hopefully haven't omitted any important conditions along the way). I've also confirmed it numerically in some special cases. One more special case in which it is easy to see that it holds is when $ q $ is uniform: the left-hand side of the inequality is then the Kullback-Leibler divergence $ D_{KL}(q\parallel p) $, which is always non-negative.

Comment: One part of your typography was abominable: I changed $D_{KL}(q||p)$ to $D_{KL}(q\parallel p),$ coded as `D_{KL}(q\parallel p)`. $\qquad\vphantom{\frac{}{\displaystyle\int}}$

Comment: I think it could help if you provide (say) a link to the physical reasons.